# How to Create Chart On Click Listener in AChartEngine Bar Chart

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am new in android. I have create `BarChart` Using `achartEngine` Library and  got Full Source Code Form this :[Link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/).

But I didn't understand how to create on-click listener to get on selected chart value . can any one help me out on this? Same Code iI used on Mine Project .

Thanks for help

Comment: any android developer please help me out on this query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a listener for bar chart. By implementing onClickListener to the view/Graphical view Instance which got drawn the chart in it.

Sample code

```
GraphicalView mChartView;

mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          /*Implement what you want*/
       }
}
```